# Cannot find cache named 'EBPICache' for Builder[public java.lang.String com.xxx.xxx.xxx.getMockOfferings(java.lang.String)] EhCache

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, ehcache, ehcache-3

I have a use case where I want to use caching for the API response, but I am not able to do it using EhCache, I am getting the error:

`Cannot find cache named 'EBPICache' for Builder[public java.lang.String com.xxx.xxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx.EBPSOfferingService.getMockOfferings(java.lang.String)] caches=[EBPICache] | key='' | keyGenerator='' | cacheManager='' | cacheResolver='' | condition='' | unless='' | sync='false'`

This is my code:

CacheProvider.java

```
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import javax.cache.Cache;
import javax.cache.CacheManager;
import javax.cache.Caching;
import javax.cache.configuration.MutableConfiguration;
import javax.cache.expiry.CreatedExpiryPolicy;
import javax.cache.expiry.Duration;
import javax.cache.spi.CachingProvider;


@EnableCaching
@Configuration("CacheProvider")
public class CacheProvider {

    private static final int cacheSize=100;

    @Bean
    public CacheManager ehCacheManager() {
        CachingProvider provider = Caching.getCachingProvider();
        CacheManager cacheManager = provider.getCacheManager();
        MutableConfiguration<Object,Object> configuration =
                new MutableConfiguration<Object, Object>()
                        .setTypes(Object.class, Object.class)
                        .setExpiryPolicyFactory(CreatedExpiryPolicy.factoryOf(Duration.ONE_HOUR));

        Cache<Object,Object> cache = cacheManager.createCache("EBPICache", configuration);
        return cacheManager;
    }
}
```

and EBPSOfferingService:

```
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.CacheEvict;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.CachePut;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.cache.annotation.CacheKey;

@Service
public class EBPSOfferingService {

    @Cacheable(cacheNames = "EBPICache")
    public String getMockOfferings(@CacheKey String can) {
        int sleepTime = 166;
        System.out.println("Sleeping for " + sleepTime + " milliseconds");
        try{
            Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception occurred while executing sleep method of thread");
        }
        return String.format("Hello! Welcome to EBPI Mock Service. The can is %s",can);
    }

    @CacheEvict(cacheNames = "EBPICache")
    public void clearMockOfferings(@CacheKey String can){
        System.out.println("clearMockOfferings invoked for CAN=" + can);
    }

    @CacheEvict(allEntries = true)
    public void clearAllOfferings(){
        System.out.println("clearAllOfferings Invoked");
    }

    @CachePut(cacheNames = "EBPICache")
    public String updateMockOfferings(@CacheKey String can, String newValue) {
        System.out.println("Updating cache entry for key= "+can+ " and new Value is "+newValue);
        return newValue;
    }
}
```

Can anyone please help me with, why this error is there and how to fix it? I have tried looking many stackOverflow answers, none of them seem to work.The solution mentioned here works: [Ehcache - Cannot find cache name for Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72723378/ehcache-cannot-find-cache-name-for-builder), but I want to use mutable configuration, because it provides much more flexibility. Thanks a lot in advance, I have been struggling for the past 2 days on this!